# Magento: Overriding Contacts controller does not work

Tags: magento

I am trying to override the Mage_Contacts_IndexController in my module. This is my config.xml file:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Magex_Corecontrollerextend>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Magex_Corecontrollerextend>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <contacts>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <magex_corecontrollerextend before="Mage_Contacts">Magex_Corecontrollerextend</magex_corecontrollerextend>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </contacts>
    </routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

I also added the controller, this is the code:

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Contacts') . DS . 'IndexController.php';

class Magex_Corecontrollerextend_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController {
    public function postAction() {
        echo 'override working!';
        die();
    }
}
```

It is placed in Magex/Corecontrollerextend/controllers/IndexController.php. The module is enabled but the override is just not working, it always calls the controller in the core. I also cleared the cache. What could be the problem? Its Magento 1.9.

Thanks!

Comment: Tested it and it works. Maybe post your `app/etc/module/Magex_Corecontrollerextend.xml` ? Or double check it. A way to debug would be to make it a "normal" controller and test if you can access is via an url, so by changing the content of your **<routers>** node with a thing like `<testing>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Magex_Corecontrollerextend</module>
                    <frontName>testing</frontName>
                </args>
            </testing>` and try to access `http://www.example.com/testing`

Comment: Make sure the Contacts controller is not overriden in any other module.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, the controller was overridden by another module. How could I handle this situation now? Overriding a controller that has been overridden?